# merging certain list elements

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of strings, some of which are all upper case, and some mixed upper and lower, and some are digits with commas:

```
lis = {"ABC","Abc","Def","1","DEF","Ghi","Jkl","MNO","1,"}
```

I would like to StringJoin adjacent elements that consist of mixed upper and lower cases to give:

```
res = {"ABC", "AbcDef","1","DEF","GhiJkl","MNO","1,"}
```

I can identify the elements of lis that contain lower case letters easily enough:

```
StringContainsQ[tes,CharacterRange["a","z"]
```

but I don't know how to make a rule to StringJoin adjacent elements that return True.  Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use[`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {a__} /; 
 And @@ (StringContainsQ[{a}, Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]]) :> 
   StringJoin[a]] 

% == res
```

> True

Faster alternatives:

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {a__}/; Nor @@ StringFreeQ[_?LowerCaseQ] @ {a}:> StringJoin[a]]
```

and

```
StringJoin /@ Split[lis, Nor @@ StringFreeQ[_?LowerCaseQ] @ {##}&]
```

Comment: Seems you beat me by a minute ;)

Comment: Thank you both for the solutions!  They work.  Unfortunately my data set is large and both these approaches take some time to execute; any thoughts for further efficiency?

Comment: @kglr - MUCH better - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Edit: Just noticed that @kglr was slightly faster in posting a very similar solution - I'll leave this here since it is at least slightly different, in that it merges arbitrarily many consecutive strings, while @kglr's solution only merges pairs]

You can use [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
SequenceReplace[
  lis,
  {strs__?(StringContainsQ@CharacterRange["a", "z"])} :> 
   StringJoin@strs
]
(* {"ABC", "AbcDef", "1", "DEF", "GhiJkl", "MNO", "1,"} *)
```

Comment: Lukas, good point re pairs vs arbitrary consecutive pairs. (+1)

Comment: i updated with a version that handles sequences of consecutive strings.

Answer (score 3):

Less elegant but fast solution:

```
lis //
    {#, StringContainsQ[#, CharacterRange["a", "z"]]} & //      
    Transpose //
    SplitBy[#, Last] & //
    Map[ If[ Last@First@#, StringJoin@(#[[All, 1]]), Sequence @@ (#[[All, 1]]) ] &]
```