# joining elements of a list by rule

Tags: string-manipulation

I am trying to generalize the responses kindly provided to my question posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206335/merging-certain-list-elements):

to StringJoin adjacent elements only when the second element begins with a designated character such as "("

```
lis = {"abc","(def)","ghi","jkl"}
```

which would produce:

```
res = {"abc(def)","ghi","jkl"}
```

I tried:

```
SequenceReplace[tes, {strs__?(StringContainsQ@
      CharacterRange["(", "("])} :> StringJoin@strs]
```

but that just gives `Lis`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fast approach using [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html):

```
lis = {"abc", "(def)", "ghi", "jkl"};
StringJoin /@ Split[lis, StringStartsQ[#2, "("] &]
(* {"abc(def)", "ghi", "jkl"} *)

lis = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
  "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", 
  "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "(ef)", "g", "m"};
StringJoin /@ Split[lis, StringStartsQ[#2, "("] &]
(* {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
"n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", 
"b", "c", "d(ef)", "g", "m"} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = {"abc", "(def)", "ghi", "jkl"};
SequenceReplace[lis, {a_, strs__?(StringStartsQ@"(")} :> StringJoin@{a, strs}]
(* {"abc(def)", "ghi", "jkl"} *)

lis = {"abc", "(def)", "ghi", "(jkl"};
SequenceReplace[lis, {a_, strs__?(StringStartsQ@"(")} :> StringJoin@{a, strs}]
(* {"abc(def)", "ghi(jkl"} *)
```

Comment: This works on the lis in the above comment, but is relatively slow.  Thanks to Alx and Rohit for their help!.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is using `StringStartsQ` with needed symbol, `"("` here, applyed to pairs of adjasent elements:

```
If[StringStartsQ[#2,"("], StringJoin[#1,#2],Sequence@@{#1,#2}]&@@@Partition[lis, 2]
```

**EDIT**

Fail was because I tested my answer with initial example only: second element of pair contains "(". Next is more general answer: any element of pair can contain "(" and length of `lis` can be odd (final edit to reveal both cases of "("):

```
lis = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
"m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", 
"z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "(ef)", "g", "g", "(ef)", "m"}    

If[Or @@ StringStartsQ[#, "("], StringJoin[#], Sequence @@ #] & /@ 
Partition[lis, UpTo@2]
```

gives

{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", \
   "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", \
   "b", "c", "d", "(ef)g", "g(ef)", "m"}

Comment: This is fast, but fails for some reason on the following: lis = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", 
   "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", 
   "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "(ef)", "g"};

Comment: I don't get the same output in the second example - the second-to-last entry is `(ef)g`, not `g(ef)`. I'm not sure how to easily fix that issue with this approach though...

Comment: @Suite401 and Lukas Lang, I edited my answer, I checked different versions of code and copyed wrong part. Now it works for me as I posted: added "(ef)", "g" and "g", "(ef)" cases.

Comment: @Alx I'm not sure that answers the question - the goal is to "to StringJoin adjacent elements only when the *second* element begins with...". I think it should therefore be `{..., "c", "d(ef)", "g", "g(ef)", "m"}`

Comment: @LukasLang, well I thought OP meant pairs of adjacent elements (my `Partition` part) and changed answer to meet his example in comment, so with my `Partition` it has now "(" in first element of pair. Probably I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Alx I not 100% sure about my interpretation either - I guess it's best if we just wait for OP to clarify :)

Comment: @Alx,Lukas Lang sorry about the ambiguity. The problem was to join pairs whose second member started with the special character.  The proposed answers work well.  Thanks!